# SWiftUI - Access UUID.uuidString Identifier in Local Notification

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, uilocalnotification

How can I access a UUID.uuidString Identifier of a Notification after being added? Let's assume I want to delete that notification, how can I call that?

I cannot use a unique string for one item because I might have two notifications in different timing sored in different Core Data entities and if I use a string for on, it will effect all the notifications for the same item.

```
// Notification
                                        
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = self.test.testData[item].title
content.body = "Notification"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
                                        
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.weekday = 5 
dateComponents.hour = 6
dateComponents.minute = 13
                                        
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
                                        
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                                        
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

Comment: You need to store identifier somewhere to use later

Comment: I'm trying to do that but I don't know how. How can I store that Identifier once the Notification is created but most importantly how can I know after that this identifier refers to one particular item? I tried to store a UUID in Core Data but I don't know how to assign it since I just add that item in Core Data and at the same time create a notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're adding local notification corresponding to a particular element in `testData`, you could add a new `attribute` to the `Core Data` object `testData` and name it `notificationIdentifier`. Recreate the model for the `testData` Core Data entity and then before saving testData entity to core data set the `notificationIdentifier` value.

```
let notificationIdentifier = UUID().uuidString
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
//...
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
//...
testEntity.notificationIdentifier = notificationIdentifier
```

Here you can get the `notificationIdentifier` for a particular `testEntity` and from the identifier you could delete an old local notification and create new local notification with new `notificationIdentifier` and update the new `notificationIdentifier` to the Core Data `testEntity`.

Comment: The problem is that TestData is a loaded json file with basic information like title and text. The core data entity, let's suppose it's called TestCoreData, has only a title attribute because that's the only one I need to show up. When I create the notification I'm looping the json file data in order to get all the titles to add inside my core data. At the same time I can have stored another attribute on my core data as an UUID but I don't know how to access it inside the ForEach

Comment: Load the `JSON` from file and store it in core data the first time. Then load the test data from core data instead of `JSON` file for displaying in `ForEach`. In the `ForEach` loop over the core data entity instead of just looping over an array of titles. Loop over entity would give you access to id as well as the title.

Comment: That's a great solution and I can do that by modifying all my code but that requires time. I was just wondering if it was possible to get the UUID inside my core data with a function by filtering the entity and return the UUID if the title is the same as the one displayed. I mean using a fetch request or something like that

Comment: Yes, use `NSPredicate` for getting the `notificationIdentifier` corresponding to a particular `title`.

Comment: How can I do that? I'm pretty ignorant with core data

Comment: Checkout the Apple documentation and also you can get more details regarding that here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-filter-core-data-fetch-requests-using-a-predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Create a unique identifier using `UUID.init().uuidString` object and save it to your `managedObject` while creating a new notification as shown below.

```
// A unique identifier
let identifier = UUID.init().uuidString

// Managed Object
let managedObject = Notifications(context: context)
managedObject.setValue(identifier, forKey: "identifier")
//...

// Notification Content
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent.init()
//...

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
//...
```

And then you can cancel the notification whenever you want.

```
context.delete(managedObject)
if context.hasChanges {
    do {
        // Cancel the registered notification with given identifier
        if let identifier = managedObject.value(forKey: "identifier") as? String {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [identifier])
            center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [identifier])
        }
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

> NOTE: This is a non-repeatable notification content.

Comment: I don't really understand the managed object passage...what is the context that you're referring to?

Comment: @xmetal This is my fault! I’m so sorry! It is a `NSManagedObjectContext` as usual.

Comment: You mean @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext ? Calling managedObjectContext doesn't work. The Notifications identifier is also unresolved